# Issue with open tab group in titanium

Tags: javascript, iphone, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have 4 tabs in a tab group. The tab transition on click of tab names is working fine. But I need to open tab2 from tab3 on click of button event in tab3. How can I do that.

Sample code,

```
<Alloy>
<Tab id="one">
    <Window class="container">
        <Label>This is the Home View</Label>
    </Window>
</Tab>
<Tab id="two">
    <Window class="container">
        <Label>This is the second View</Label>
    </Window>
</Tab>
<Tab id="three">
    <Window class="container">
        <Button onClick="saveLang">Proceed</Button>
    </Window>
</Tab>

</Alloy>
```

**Controller:**

```
function saveLang()
{
// How can we open only tab2 here
// I tried open index, the loading time taking long and also it is opening tab1 But I need to open tab2 for this event
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*I am not currently on my system , still few issues/comments which I can mention are :*

Firstly I doubt your tabs would not work properly as they are not enclosed in [TabGroup](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup).

So your view should be like :

```
<Alloy>
  <TabGroup id="myTabGrp"> //Tabgroup Added
    <Tab id="one">
        <Window class="container">
            <Label>This is the Home View</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>

    <Tab id="two">
        <Window class="container" id="winTwo">
            <Label>This is the second View</Label>
        </Window>
    </Tab>

    <Tab id="three">
        <Window class="container">
            <Button onClick="saveLang">Proceed</Button>
        </Window>
     </Tab>
  </TabGroup>
</Alloy>
```

Now when `saveLang` method gets called in **controller** we can call [`setActiveTab`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-method-setActiveTab) method:

```
function saveLang() {
  $.myTabGrp.setActiveTab($.two);
}
```

**Edit :** For reloading/refreshing content of a window in Tab , add [focus event of window](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-focus) in your **controller** :

```
$.winTwo.addEventListener('focus',function(e) { 
    alert('focus');
});
```

Hope it is helpful.

Comment: I don't know for some reason, If I include id for tab group, I am getting an Application error. Say that 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'a.inex.open') at index.js (line2)

Comment: you should use `$.myTabGrp.open();` because root element is now tabgroup and it has `id = 'myTabGrp'`

Comment: Great. It is working. But Is there any way to reload before activating the tab. Because with out reloading the data content doesn't get updated.

Comment: i think [window's focus event](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Window-event-focus) will be helpful in this case.

Comment: Yes But Need to refresh, how can we do refresh the page

Comment: what do you want to refresh , content in window ( like `Label` in window2 ) ? So update it in focus event `$.myLabelId.setText('changed')` ? Or if you loading data from **XHR request** call the function here.

Comment: also the thing you are asking is totally different from this question, maybe you should ask another question if you still face difficulty.